# How to expand nested HTML5 <details> elements to make a link target visible?

Tags: css, html

I have a html5 page which contains something like this:

```
<details>
  <summary>X and Y</summary>
  <details id="x">
    <summary>X</summary>
    Long text about x.
  </details>
  <details id="y">
    <summary>Y</summary>
    Long text about Y.
  </details>
</details>
A lot of other stuff.
<a href="#x>Go to X</a>
<a href="#y>Go to Y</a>
```

I already use a CSS details:target spec to highlight the link target when a user clicks on one of the "Go to X/Y" links.  However, if the top-level details-element is not expanded, the user can't see it and it seems like it wouldn't work.

So is there a way (preferably only html5 + css) to expand the top-level details-element when a link targeting some of its children is clicked?

Comment: the **details** tag has an attribute called **open="open"** - then you can toggle natively - but it looks like it is only supported in Chrome - view this link in Google Chrome: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5-whats-new/template/index.html#5 -

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like to have it toggled to open automatically when a link targets the details element.  But it seems it's undoable without JS.

Comment: yes i would have to agree .. that you would need some type of JS due to attributes for the details tag are still experimental

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way for now is using Javascript. You can read this for already written code: http://www.sitepoint.com/fixing-the-details-element/

Comment: Thanks. Too bad that automatic expansion is not the standard behavior, though.

Answer (score -2):

I wrote this code

```js
<script>
  function openDetailsNested() {
    var listOpen = document.querySelectorAll("details[open]");
    if(listOpen.length > 0) {
      for(var i=0; i<listOpen.length; i++) {
        var elem = listOpen[i];  
        while (elem) {
          if (elem.matches("DETAILS")) {
            elem.setAttribute("open",""); 
          }
          elem = elem.parentElement;
        }      
      }
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("load", openDetailsNested,true);
</script>
```

Comment: When you click **Run code snippet** button you get an error message: **Error:** `{
  "message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 12,
  "colno": 8
}`